How to pass client ip address via Nginx reverse proxy to FastAPI
I am trying to pass the request client IP address to a FastAPI backend via Nginx.
Example FastAPI endpoint:
@app.post('/api/example')
def send_order(data: SomeDataType, request: Request, response: Response):
    print(request.client.host) # ip address of client

This works fine, until the backend is behind a reverse proxy. (Provided by Nginx.)
Now, it just logs the local IP address as the address of the host. (In this case a 172.X.X.X type of address.
Here is how I have configured Nginx:
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5555/api;
    proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
}

I thought this should be enough. I did some futher reading which suggested perhaps I need to add another middleware into the backend. Currently FastAPI is using the CORS middleware, but nothing else.
I'm not sure if this information is correct or not. This is where I got stuck and couldn't find any examples which I could make sense of.

Haven't tried it yet, but it seems that you should run the ASGI web server with flags that make it trust the headers added by proxy. In case of uvicorn you should run it with --proxy-headers and also --forwarded-allow-ips='*'. In production it's recomended to specify proxy ip explicitly instead of wildcard.

This is how I am currently running the uvicorn server: python3 -m example_package_name. I would guess that I need to add something to this line: config = uvicorn.Config('example_package_name:app', host='0.0.0.0', port=5555, log_level='info'). Any idea what to add? I can't see to find a documentation page for this.

I managed to find the answer here: https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/master/uvicorn/config.py
It seems that only proxy_headers=True is required

If you are running Uvicorn programmatically:

Add: proxy_headers=True

uvicorn.Config(
    'example_package_name:app',
    host='0.0.0.0',
    port=5555,
    log_level='info',
    proxy_headers=True,
)


The relevant documentation and implementation can be found here and here, respectively.
